# Active admin: Custom check_box input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I need to show a dynamic list of values to show on an Active Admin edit screen as checkboxes, where the list comes from code (not database).  I can do that pretty easily, but I can't figure out how to show some of those as being checked.  [image: checkboxes]

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
names = %w(Sam Darcy Ernie)
pairs = Hash[names.zip(names)]
f.input :buddies, as: :check_boxes, collection: pairs, checked: %w(Sam)
```

What I was hoping for is to show the 3 checkboxes and have the "Sam" box checked.  None are checked though.  What can I do to control which checkboxes are checked?

Comment: You could set Sam checked with javascript easily but knowing whether Sam was intentionally unchecked on subsequent edit screens would be difficult, this really begs to be managed as a :has_many relationship.

Comment: @MikeK. Thanks, I was hoping that AA's check_boxes supported setting the "checked" attribute on page render.  As you mentioned though, has_many would be ideal, but when I do that, I can only iterate and display what's already been saved, not names that are not already associated as buddies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up with the following that functions as desired:

```
people = [
  ['Sam', 0, checked: true],
  ['Darcy', 0],
  ['Ernie', 0],
]
f.input :buddies, as: :check_boxes, collection: people
```

It seems that the array items beyond the first 2 are used to set attributes.  So in my case, the "checked" attribute is set, resulting in the element attribute of `checked="checked"`

I'm still interested in knowing if there is a better way of handling this though.